# paste to active cell VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I need to paste text from a Word table to an Excel worksheet, but because some of the cells in Word have line breaks that I need to preserve in Excel, a straight copy/paste is not an option--Excel interprets any line breaks as cell breaks. To work around this, I'm replacing the line breaks in Word with dummy text (e.g., "@@@"), then pasting into Excel, and finally running find/replace to replace the dummy text with an Excel-compatible line break (alt+0010).

I recorded a macro to do this:

```
Sub IDA()
'
' IDA Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
Sheets("Deployment").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
Selection.Replace What:="@@@", Replacement:="" & Chr(10) & "", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

But when I move the the next block of text to paste, it pastes back to the original destination. I can see the sheet ("Deployment") and range ("C2") are both hard-coded. I tried removing those lines, but that broke the script--nothing happens when I run it.

I could simplify the script to just do the search and replace, but I don't trust the other users to use the paste special option when they paste into Excel, which means the spreadsheet may end up with other formatting from Word that I don't want.

How do I modify my script so it simply pastes into the active worksheet and cell?

Comment: To clarify, each new block of text is going into a new sheet, so I can't hard-code the sheet. Also, the spreadsheet is based on a template, but the sheet names are customized for each specific deliverable, so there aren't any set sheet names.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the 2 hardcoded lines, and use:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial ....
```

so the end code:

```
Sub IDA()
'
' IDA Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
Selection.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
Selection.Replace What:="@@@", Replacement:="" & Chr(10) & "", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that, but the macro stopped working after that.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an easy fix. Simply clicking the "Use Relative References" button (directly under the record button) prior to recording the macro did the trick. It yielded the following script:

```
Sub IDA()
'
' IDA Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False
    Selection.Replace What:="@@@", Replacement:="" & Chr(10) & "", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient code, but it will do the job for myself and the three other people doing this a few times per quarter. There's never enough data being copied to notice a difference. A lot of effort to satisfy the bellyaching of one coworker who couldn't be bothered with a whopping two keystrokes and ensure the paste special option is used.